# 301 redirecting *.php to non-*.php

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make it so requests to `http://www.domain.tld/folder/filename.php` get `301` redirected to `http://www.domain.tld/folder/filename` (ie. no php) and am having some difficulty doing so.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

RewriteRule (.*)\.php $1 [L,R=301]
```

First RewriteRule works as I'd expect. Second...  not so much.

As written requests to `http://www.domain.tld/folder/filename.php` get `301` redirected to `http://www.domain.tld/home/username/public_html/folder/filename`

If I change that last RewriteRule to do `/$1` instead of `$1` I get directed to `http://www.domain.tld/filename` and not `http://www.domain.tld/folder/filename`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your .htaccess like this for hiding `.php` extension:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```